# How to open Android hotspot using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, hotspot

I want to set ssid and password of wifi hotspot in android using flutter.
I used [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) but most of it's functions are deprecated.
is there any other way to do so?

I think using method channels would be better but I need code to open hotspot from kotlin/
give me full example of kotlin code please to open hotspot and set ssid, password

Answer (score 0):

> val wifiManager =
> applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as
> WifiManager val method =
> wifiManager.javaClass.getMethod("setWifiApEnabled",
> WifiConfiguration::class.java, Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType) val
> wifiConfig = WifiConfiguration() wifiConfig.SSID = "MyHotSpot"
> wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "mypassword"
> wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)

method.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfig, true)

Comment: i can't find this package, can you send it's link please

Comment: Then do using MEthod Channel thats is the Kotlin Code